# Can I get multiple test results from one test method called recursively using python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a few hundred API calls I need to test for HTTP 200 and have a simple test method that verifies the code == 200 and a method that calls the test method.

I would like to be able to see each time the test method is recursively called as a separate test result. One way I could do that is just generate a file and append to it a new test method for each URL and then run that file but I'd rather not do that if there's an easier way.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I may be able do this?

Comment: The question's primarily opinion-based as it's asking for recommendation. Please go through [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm asking if it's technically feasible to run one test recursively and have the results be reflected as multiple test results. I'm looking for a technical solution not opinions.

Comment: I think that this is not opinion-based (is a recursive test possible), but the solution to your underlying problem is opinion based.  Thus I don't think this question will help you much.